# how to prevent Async in NodeJS - wait for task a to complete before starting task b

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, google-speech-api

I am in need to wait for task A to complete before executing task B code.

task A is to convert audio file and

task B uses the converted audio for further process.

because task A store new audio file to particular directory and task B is trying to access the file which does not exist my code breaks.

How do I make sure task B code executes once the new audio file is saved to a directory?

## code

```
var track = fileURL;//your path to source file

  ffmpeg(track)
  .toFormat('flac')
  .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
  })
  .on('progress', function (progress) {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(progress));
      console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
  })
  .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Processing finished !');
  })
  .save(path.join(__dirname, '/public/downloads/Test.flac'));//path where you want to save your file
```

The above part of the code takes file from uploads folder converts it to new file format and saves it to the downloads directory.

You can see below I am trying to access the file `(Test.flac)` in downloads folder. There is lot more code but I need to execute this block of code only after completion of above task.

```
  const Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
  const projectId = 'uliq-68823';
  // Instantiates a client
  const speechClient = Speech({
   projectId: projectId
  });

  // The name of the audio file to transcribe

  const fileName2 = path.join(__dirname, '/public/downloads/' + 'Test.flac');

  // Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
  const file2 = fs.readFileSync(fileName2);
  const audioBytes = file2.toString('base64');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fluent-ffmpeg` library uses streams to process your files. Therefore if you want to execute code after the stream is done, call your code in the callback called on the `'end'` event of the stream.

Example:

```
var track = fileURL;//your path to source file

ffmpeg(track)
.toFormat('flac')
.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
})
.on('progress', function (progress) {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(progress));
      console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
})
.on('end', function () {
      console.log('Processing finished !');
      // USE THE FILE HERE
      // <----------------
})
.save(path.join(__dirname, '/public/downloads/Test.flac'));
```

Comment: so now the file gets saved to downloads folder but the code inside function(error, result) {} does not seems to execute and in terminal I see the cursor waiting endlessly.  what does file parameter hold?

Comment: if I dont use callback I get : TypeError: ffmpeg(...).toFormat(...).on(...).on(...).on(...).save(...).then is not a function

Comment: What is ffmpeg ? Which node package ?

Comment: My bad, it's a different library. I checked the doc, in your library, it is a stream, so call your code in the `.on('end', function(){})`. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use async water fall package which is used to serialize the function so that second function will run after first 
here is link [package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall)